# Cookie not set in request header after set withcredential = true

Tags: angular, cookies, cors

I am call api after login and in login response header set-cookie is pass and cookie set in browser. but when i am try to make other request there is no cookie pass in request header. i have try to add withcredential = true and also allow CORS with all required headers.
cookie set in browser in login response

```
.AspNetCore.Identity.Application    
expires 2018-07-27T14:26:34.000Z
httpOnly    true
path    /
secure  true
value   CfDJ8IpQ2KMnnJJCu-Bxqp-xHNOQGuT6Ig74z_z6fhAba0WGCMyq7er9Zo87dX36mvr3vHm827XQFM_8cNQiv811mitpYZ4rRVRp4iV3RfpDkqGL-4UizEGUkJfSxxkFzIbVEEJNwIJXf5iFFlbC7Fw8zKDn7DYJN70iniH4HE-bzqJ4KXSsKnCyqePsYyi6iJ0_Rkk_TiE-TXggnFqrU_8n5XPcYaRVeinAeHRZ2xmJbcVrOwFAV1-D8zwgpnJxs2WaLsM9h5IoqdV1wOwyT-Awoy0QqAtTiUPs5h5Gh52HubsBcWLPKE_FbzfmK_1HsDGH1e1PIHYJaIgLx-q0trTSGK-22wvOnqMipax94zoO6mfF2Pbrz7NM-eJBBCTkSoNYXVIj8EpRPJXhk8uLKC9rqon2hA4qHpnrUWWdz1LT7FYzHjnhAx3hctXr2laQgc3ipT410zI15tl5XIIjEbqr9D5E6o-4MkcSCLsHCLkaurSmoQWF2VRQ8OuVHFz6Z7XTu7myAsCFWf3INcV-WBtJY6l9Luk2D7uenofPGFZ8D4fDL0oaPqvAKve6N8r2Q_eDXEVf-
```

see my code

```
Request header from browser console
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  27
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host    localhost:44354
Origin  http://localhost:4200
Referer http://localhost:4200/changepassword
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
withCredentials true
```

my code:-

```
changePassword(changePasswordModel: ChangePassword): Observable<ApiResponse> {
    const body = JSON.stringify(changePasswordModel)

     let enco : any = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .set('withCredentials', 'true')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    return this._httpClient.post(this.identityAPIEndPoint + 'Account/ChangePassword', body, { headers: enco, withCredentials: true}).pipe(
      map((response: Response) => <ApiResponse>response.json()));
  }
```

i am using angular 5 with HttpClient For Post Request. 
Is i am mission something.
Please give me hint.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem here is the `scope` of your cookie. For more see the `Scope of cookies` section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies).

So you should set the same `path` for all your pages so the cookie will be available from all pages. For example, you can set the `path` to be `/` or the base path of your application.

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is a response header so it should be provided in the response and not in the request: see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials).

And the `withCredentials` option isn't an HTTP header at all it's an option which should be passed in the `options` object: see this [link](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient).

Also, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) article for more about CORS.

Comment: Hello thanks for  reply but my cookie path is alreay same as you said like "/", see i have add my cookie which set in browser

Comment: can you also provide the URLs of calls you're making for login and for the second call also?