# Ajax call with withCredentials: true is not sending cookie in request

Tags: django, ajax, session-cookies, django-cors-headers

My scenario: 
**example.com** is a django page which is being visited by user. session is set by server. Now, I have frontend app on another domain called **xyz.com**, Now, I need to call APIs on **example.com**, so I am trying to make ajax call with `withCredentials: true`. but it does not seems to sending cookie 'sessionId' in request.

I have already seen some stack overflow answers, but suggested answers are not working. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911710/jquery-ajax-call-not-sending-cookie) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230341/http-cookies-and-ajax-requests-over-https/10249123) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51327149/cookie-not-set-in-request-header-after-set-withcredential-true)

What I have been trying : 
My backend is written in Django, so I tried setting

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
    # Cross Origin Request Settings (CROS)
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'GET',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'PATCH',
    'DELETE',
    'OPTIONS'
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'x-requested-with',
    'content-type',
    'accept',
    'origin',
    'authorization',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'cache',
    'cookie',
)

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    '*'
]

SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False

SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'example.com'
```

I am using ajax to make api calls on example.com

```
jQuery.ajax({
 url: "http://example.com/api/v1/admin/settings/",
 dataType: 'json',
 xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
 success: function(data) {
 console.log(data);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering to my question so that it can help in case if someone is stuck at same situation.

I found out that in django `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE` is by default `Lax`.

> 'Lax' (default): provides a balance between security and usability for websites that want to maintain user’s logged-in session after the user arrives from an external link.
>
> In the GitHub scenario, the session cookie would be allowed when
>   following a regular link from an external website and be blocked in
>   CSRF-prone request methods (e.g. POST).

So I had to set it to None in settings to allow browser sending cookie.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
```

refer docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#session-cookie-samesite)